# How to fix: even list elements not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list

I have an unordered list with list elements containing links, in a hidden div, that will be visible when an icon is clicked in the page.
List becomes visible, but only the odd list elements have a link.

Tried different number of list elements, both Chrome and Firefox, won't work.

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-sm-1 " style="display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;align-items:center;position:relative;">
    <i onClick="ToggleMenu()" id="menuopen" class="fas fa-bars" style="cursor:pointer"></i>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="menuinvisible" id="themenu" style="background-color:white;position: absolute;right: 10px;top: 62px;padding-right: 17px;">
        <ul>
            <li style="display:block">
                <a href="pages/contact.php">Contact 1</a>
            </li>
            <li style="display:block">
                <a href="pages/contact.php">Contact 2</a>
            </li>
            <li style="display:block">
                <a href="pages/contact.php">Contact 3</a>
            </li>
            <li style="display:block">
                <a href="pages/contact.php">Contact 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <!--END MENU-->

</div>
<!--END CONTAINER-->
```

JS to toggle visibility of `<div class="menuinvisible" id="themenu">`

```js
function ToggleMenu(){
    document.getElementById('menuopen').classList.toggle('fa-bars');
    document.getElementById('menuopen').classList.toggle('fa-times');   

    document.getElementById('themenu').classList.toggle('menuvisible'); 
    document.getElementById('themenu').classList.toggle('menuinvisible');       
}
```

CSS:

```css
.menuinvisible{
    display:none;   
}

.menuvisible{
    display:block;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite confused, you want to show the whole list? or only the elements that have a link?, if you want to show all the elements it work with this:

```
function ToggleMenu(){
    document.getElementById('menuopen').classList.toggle('fa-bars');
    document.getElementById('menuopen').classList.toggle('fa-times');   

    document.getElementById('themenu').classList.toggle('menuvisible'); 
    document.getElementById('themenu').classList.toggle('menuinvisible');       
};


 document.querySelector('#menuopen').addEventListener('click', ToggleMenu);
```